# How to understand SHAP value for an autoencoder model

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoder, shap

I am very new to SHAP recently. I am very curious about what the 'feature importance' mean for an autoencoder model.

Suppose I have a well-trained AE model. If I run the code something like

```
e = shap.KernelExplainer(autoencoder.predict, X_train.values)
shap_values = e.shap_values(X_train.values)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_train)
```

So I am wondering what does the outcome means? Since it is an autoencoder neural network. Does the 'feature importance' means which feature is more important for this model? Also, should I replace the X_train with X_test? Autoencoder is known for its ability of abnormal detection. If I put some abnormal samples into

```
shap_values = e.shap_values(Abnormal_sample.values)
```

What does that mean?

Also, I found that the SHAP model does not require any training target value (the y values for any neural network models). So how it defines the 'feature importance'?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Shap shows why/how your predicted values are different from baseline. No target is needed.

Comment: Thanks! I also found when I train the same neural network with the same training dataset (basically the same script) again and again. The output of the SHAP is quite different every time. Even I fixed the random seed when dividing the original dataset into training and testing. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: I believe Shap is deterministic. Check if `autoencoder.predict(X_train.values)` changes with each run

Comment: where did you get the example code of shap values for autoencoder?

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, "Does the 'feature importance' means which feature is more important for this model?"

Yes, If you consider a buggy model, then feature importance means which features are mostly responsible for predicting its being buggy.